# Python-Idle not working after reinstall - cygwin conflict?

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, python-idle

I've used Python under Cygwin for a number of years, but it stopped working, I think when I installed Python under the base Win10. In desperation, I blew away my Cygwin and reinstalled it from scratch, together with Python and Vim. It still didn't work, it seems because Cygwin's $PATH was including Window's %PATH%, and picking up the Windows Python executable and libraries. I found a way to stop that, but the Windows Python now doesn't work, though as of when, I not sure.

So I've just uninstalled the Windows Python (and a Windows Python2) and reinstalled the latest version (3.10.8). It works from the command line, but Idle doesn't. Calling it up from the icon in the start menu under Recently Added, it says this action is only valid for products that are installed. Invoking it from the newly added Python 3.10 group in my start menu just gives a busy cursor momentarily, then nothing. That icon points to
C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\pythonw.exe "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw"

Help, anyone?
(And yes, I've just rebooted one more time - no change. And yes, I did reboot after uninstalling the previous Python.)

Comment: Reminder that Idle on cygwin requires that X11 be installed and running when you start Idle.

Comment: I remove all windows folders from my cygwin path, and only add those that I actually need as I need them. In windows, I set `CYGWIN_NOWINPATH=1` in my user env vars. In `.bash_profile`, I add back necessary windows path folder(s). The only one I add is the folder holding `go.exe`. I *never* run windows python within cygwin. I always use the cygwin python 3. I use `alternatives` to let python2 and python3 co-exists in cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Further googling came up with at least a partial answer. My system environment variables contained
TCL_LIBRARY C:\Program Files (x86)\CSR\BlueSuite 2.6.6
That other program installations should fiddle with this is a bit naughty, in my book.

However, the IDLE entry in Recently Added Programs at the top of my start menu still gives a pop-up "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed". In fact it seems to refer to a Python2.7 which I've removed. Can't imagine what Window was thinking of. I'll just remove that from the top of the start menu.